# Misplaced chords over lyrics

Tags: lilypond

I use Lilypond to make scores with only chords and lyrics. However, I don't understand the chords placement I get with the following snippet:

```
<<                                                                                                                                                           
  \new ChordNames
    \chordmode {
      a2:m a4:m a4:m/gis
      c2:/g c
      d2:/fis f2:m6 c2 c4 f4 c1                                             
     }
  \new Lyrics
    \lyricmode{
      " "8 "When I try to get through"4. " "2 \break                        
      " "8 "On the telephone to"4. "you"2 \break                            
      ""2. "There'll be nobody"4 "home."4 " "2. " "1 \break
    }
>>  
    \layout {                                                               
      ragged-right = ##t                                                    
      \context { \Score                                                     
        \omit BarNumber                                                     
      }                                                                     
      \context { \Lyrics                                                           
        \override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-affinity = ##f                             
        \override LyricText.parent-alignment-X = #LEFT                               
        \override LyricText.self-alignment-X = #LEFT                                 
      }
    }
```

which results in:
[image]

In the first line, the last two chords should appear **after** the text, as in the third line. Can someone explain why they are aligned in this way and how to get the desired result?

Comment: Related: [LilyPond lyrics affecting horizontal spacing in score](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/131889/lilypond-lyrics-affecting-horizontal-spacing-in-score)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, which is to fill the empty lyric notes with something, as in:

```
\lyricmode{
  " "8 "When I try to get through"4. "__"2 \break                        
  " "8 "On the telephone to"4. "you"2 \break                            
  ""2. "There'll be nobody"4 "home."4 " "2. " "1 \break
}
```

which would result in
[image]

To avoid the underscores showing up. I found this trick to add invisible text:

```
spacetwo = \lyricmode{
  \override Lyrics.LyricText.color = #white
  "X"2
  \override Lyrics.LyricText.color = #black
  }
```

Then:

```
    \lyricmode{
      " "8 "When I try to get through"4. \spacetwo \break
      " "8 "On the telephone to"4. "you"2 \break
      ""2. "There'll be nobody"4 "home."4 " "2. " "1 \break
    }
```

Now the result looks exactly the way I wanted:

[image]

Hope this is useful to someone!

Comment: I wonder why such laborious a code is used (Lilypond) to get chords over lyrics when an application or two exists that does the same by typing a brackets around the chord name, i.e. [G#m] within the text.  The chord is automatically placed over word, or any where you want it in a line of verse, and it is stored so as the chord is repeated in the lyrics, it can be tapped or clicked upon from a now stored list of chords places it where you want it.  You only write the chord once in [X] format then tap it from the list.  No code necessary.

Comment: Lilypond is much more flexible, though: for example, you could use the same chords above a stave (or the same words under a stave), or show the chords on their own with barlines, or other combinations, simply by changing the `\score` block — very handy for generating e.g. lead sheets _and_ chords sheets _and scores for the same song.